# how do I to the auto-completion of combobox match any part of string not only start of string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

let's say that I have items as it:

```
PHP Hypertext Processor
PHP_FOO PHP framework
C#  .NET framework 
Obama american
Bill gates american
```

I'm looking for a way to that any text entered in comobobox search in any part of combobox items, not only in start of string and set it into auto-completation suggest.

For example:

text entered: `Processor` or `PHP` or `Hypertext` match: `PHP Hypertext Processor`
text entered: `american` match: `Obama` and `Bill gates` 
etc..

The matches items should be defined as suggestion in combobox.

**UPDATE**
my current code:

```
 private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(object item in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            string val = (string)item;
            string[] words = val.Split(' ');

            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (word == comboBox1.Text)
                {
                    ////the difficult now it is as set the val variable value in combobox suggestions box?
                }
            }

            i++;
        }

    }
```

how I do it? I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DJKRAZE:is not. you can post an example how do it? the difficult is show stirng as suggest in comobobox.

Comment: you can do this many ways... check on the key press or key up events. I would use an or create a string[]  along with a switch statement.. what code have you tried so far.. you have to be willing to try coding something first..

Comment: since you state that you are looking for any word that is contained in that string variable look at the .Contains method

Comment: I think you can't handling with suggestion box of control.

Answer (score 0):

your loop should be changed as well.. if you know that it will have text use something like this for starters.

```
foreach (string text in combobox1.Items.Cast<string>())
{
     //do stuff with the text
}
```

Comment: thanks. but how I set the matched item in suggestion box of comobobox?

Comment: if you have two combo boxes set it by using Items.Add method they have add and remove.. now for you.. you will have to figure out your own logic in regards to adding and removing values so you don't have duplicates.. but an easy way around that would be to Clear() or Delete before adding.. it's your call